# Android application not closing on backpress because of sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

> I used sharedpreferences in my login activity and if the value is
>   available in sharedpreference it will open HomeActivity
>
> But, the problem arises when i press back button app goes to my
>   previous activity ie. loginActivity where I'm checking the
>   sharedpreference value to open HomeActivity. This making my app to
>   return back to HomeActivity.

**LoginActivity.java** code

```
@Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            //In onresume fetching value from sharedpreference
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SharedPrefConfig.SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(SharedPrefConfig.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);
            username = sharedPreferences.getString(SharedPrefConfig.USERNAME_SHARED_PREF, null);
            if(loggedIn){
                //We will start the Home Activity
                     Intent intent = new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

**HomeActivity.java** code

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
   Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: set nohistory="true" to Login Activity in a manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please finish login activity when intent call means
 add this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
                 finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on logout then write this Code. So it will redirect you to LoginActivity.

```
    Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            logoutIntent.putExtra("isFromLogout", true);
                            logoutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(logoutIntent);
                            finish();
```

And in LoginActivity write below code.

```
boolean isFromLogout = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isFromLogout", false);
        if (!isTaskRoot() && !isFromLogout) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
```

Above Scenario will help you if you want to logout from your application. Now when you are on your Home Page and when you press back button and you want to close your app in background so use below code.

```
 private void minimizeApp() {
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How your app should work?

1. Just close app after closing `HomeActivity`.

Simpliest way is to finish login activity after start home activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

2. After closing `HomeActivity` show login activity.

You can clear `SharedPreferences` in `onDestroy` method of `HomeActivity` class. So in `onResume` of login activity whould get nothing and don't open anything.

Another way - check `HomeActivity` result. For that need to change opening code - place `startActivityForResult` method call.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Then in `onActivityResult` method of login activity make some action for disabling `HomeActivity` open (for example, again clean `SharedPreferences`).

Answer (score -1):

Use the finish() method. It will destroy the activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);    
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```